# Excel 2010 Pivot Table - Wrong Field Shown in Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

My pivot tables are pulling in data from an incorrect field. I have a data set that is around 20 columns by 70,000 rows; so not too large.

I have a "Transaction Date" field in my data. When I select this field in my pivot table, I do not get dates. Instead, I get the text data from an adjacent field in the underlying data set. Refreshing the pivot table and removing / re-adding the field in question do not resolve this issue.

I created the Pivot Tables several months ago and update the underlying data monthly. I have not had a problem until just now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No. I used the standard "Insert > Pivot Table" command.

Comment: Yes, I see the same thing happening.